# How to deploy script as Web App so I don't need to authorize every time or copy the authorization when I copy the invoice

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I have a Google Apps invoice spreadsheet which has a script which creates a menu item to an Email function that does the following:

1.- Emails the invoice.

2.- Copies the invoice, with updated info.

3.- Opens the copied invoice.

Everything works fine, except I'm required to authorize every new copy of the invoice's attached script.

Scope of the script project:

```
6 OAuth Scopes required by the script:
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

Question: Is it possible to either centralize the script (deploy as Web App) so I don't need to authorize every time or copy the authorization when I copy the invoice.

I've tried to deploy it as Web App but it's not obvious how to include the script in the sheets.

Every invoice needs the same "Email" function, and the script essentially just gets field values for the email and increments the invoice number when it's copied.

The only issue is the script authorization, and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization didn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Deploy your script as an add-on. Check the App Script guides and reference documentation for information on how to create an add-on.

Comment: Alternately, do not begin working on the copy. Always work from the same document, and let the copies be snapshots. If you later need to use your script function in the copies, you can authorize that specific copy then.

Comment: The problem w/ using an add-on (unless I don't know what I'm doing), is that I need to publish it. It doesn't use generic code.
Is there any other way?



@tehhowch I considered using 1 pre authroized sheet as a template, but it doesn't work well for our workflow, or incrementing the Invoice Number... I can figure workarounds, but I think getting over authorization still looks like the easiest option.

Comment: @I'-'I that's what tehhowch proposed... if nobody else can think of a better way then that's my failback position. Thanks.